# multiple launch by Astrogator

Tags: stk-agi

I want to launch 24 satellites in group of 3 by use of STK Astrogator. How should I do it??
I changed the epoch, raan and true anomaly but I could not make it.
thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit your question to let us know what you currently tried, otherwise it is impossible to give you guidance.